# c# same tag name on a xml element

Tags: c#, xml, xmlnode, xmlnodelist

i got this case, i get all the elements on a xmlnodelist using the function getelementesbytagname(""), but sometimes i can had something like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Element xsi:schemaLocation="http://localhost/AML/CaseInvestigationMangement/Moduli/XmlImportControls/xsdBorrow.xsd xsd2009027_kor21.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<nodo>
    <nombre>nodo1</nombre>
    <dato>1</dato>
    <otronodo>
        <nombre>nododentrodenodo</nombre>
        <dato2>23</dato2>
    </otronodo>
</nodo>
<nodo>
    ...
</nodo>
</Element>
```

if y search all the nodes by the name "nombre" well i get the nodo nombre and the otronodo nombre.

can i get only the name of the nodo node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want only the `nombre` values that have a `nodo` parent, but it's possible you want any `nombre` from any child of `Element`. With XPath and `SelectNodes`, you can do either, so I've included both below. `SelectNodes` returns `XmlNodeList`, just like `GetElementsByTagName()` does.

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();

doc.LoadXml(@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8"" ?>
<Element>
    <nodo>
        <nombre>nodo1</nombre>
        <dato>1</dato>
        <otronodo>
            <nombre>nododentrodenodo</nombre>
            <dato2>23</dato2>
        </otronodo>
    </nodo>
    <nodo>
        <nombre>nodo2</nombre>
    </nodo>
    <frodo>
        <nombre>frodo nodo</nombre>
    </frodo>
</Element>
");

//  Any nombre whose parent is a nodo
var nodosNombres = doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//nodo/nombre");

//  Any nombre belonging to any child of Element
var topNombres = doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/Element/*/nombre");
```